# Create table with one attribute depending on another

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I just started learning PostgreSQL and wanted to create a complex table, but have no idea how to go about it. I want to create a table in which it contains `name`, `start_date` and `end_date`.
The end date should be `30 + start_date`.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, you *don't* store a functionally dependent value redundantly. That just bloats the table and is not as reliable as dynamically deriving the additional column.

Just store `name` and `start_date`. You can create a [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html) that adds the `end_date` dynamically. Or just use the expression `start_date + 30 AS end_date` in a query where needed.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  foo_id     serial PRIMARY KEY  -- add surrogate PK, names are rarely good for that
, foo        text NOT NULL       -- "name" is hardly ever a good name
, start_date date NOT NULL DEFAULT now()::date
);

CREATE VIEW foo_plus AS
SELECT *, start_date + 30 AS end_date
FROM   foo
ORDER  BY start_date;  -- optional
```

In Postgres you can just add an [`integer` to a `date`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype.html) to add days.

About `serial`:

- [Auto increment SQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9875223/auto-increment-sql-function/9875517#9875517)

If the calculation of the dependent values is *expensive* (unlike this trivial example), consider a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

Comment: I dont want a view, is there anyway so that end_date can automatically be updated in table when I insert start_date ?

Comment: @JohnConstantine: Triggers. [Here is a related answer with complete code examples.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657048/constraints-and-assertions-in-postgresql/9657503#9657503). But that's an inferior design for this simple case. I wouldn't even use a view here. Just `start_date + 30 AS end_date` at almost no cost and without all the possible complications introduced by triggers.